# Set default selected all simple products of bundle products

Tags: magento-1.9, default, bundle-product

i was trying to set to all my bundle products with all the options selected.

Instead of doing it manually, i wants to make it by code.

I think i should get first all the bundleproducts from my shop and then makes a loop to change all the simple products of it, and put it default, but i cant make it and i haven´t seen nothing like that.

Anyone have any idea?

This is how my front-end is show.

[image]

And this is on backend:
[image]

I dont know which is the best solution, i think it could be easy if i change it on backend, not?

The result should be all the options selected by default.

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: How could be more specific?
It´s simple.
I have a lot of bundle products.
I want to make a script to change all the attribute selects of their simple products.
I think i can´t explain better.

Comment: Are you talking about frontend or backend? Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: @Vsld  upload new information

Answer (score 0):

Finally i make it by jQuery:

```
// enable all simple products
    table.find('.bundlecheckbox input.checkbox').each(function() {
        this.click();
    });
```